# Foreach Loop Through Array for Datatables With Eloquent Relations

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, datatables, eloquent

I have 2 tables in my database - `Bots` and `Results`. The bots table is to have information on each specific bot alone. Each bot should have several results attached to it. I will simplify what I have in my columns:

**Bots Table**

```
Device | Info1 | Info2  | Info3
```

**Results Table**

```
Device | Data1 | Data2 | Data3
```

As you can see, each table has the column named `Device`. Now, I have 2 Models of course for each table - the regarding info is as follows:

**Bot Model**

```
public function results()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Result', 'device', 'device');
}
```

**Result Model**

```
public function bots()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Bot', 'device', 'device');
}
```

I have a view with a Datatable in it which I am trying to list every `Device` and Every `Result` corresponding to that `Device`. What I have here is an example of what was made before eloquent relations was brought in. I use to only have the Results table, so therefore it was farely simple to do a foreach and loop throught every result I had to display on the Datatabes

**Datatables View**

```
@foreach ($results as $result)
<tr>
  <td>
    {{ $result->device }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ $result->info1 }} 
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ $result->info2 }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ $result->info3 }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ $result->data1 }} 
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ $result->data2 }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ $result->data3 }}
  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

How can I get this to work now that the device name and information is actually stored in a separate table?

Comment: Can you show the code for your route/controller method?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch your device information with its associated `results` using [eager](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) load like this

```
$bots = Bot::with('results')->get();
```

Now in view you can do it like this

```
@foreach ($bots as $bot)
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ $bot->device }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $bot->info1 }} 
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $bot->info2 }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $bot->info3 }}
        </td>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($bot->results as $result)
        <tr>
          <td>
            {{ $result->data1 }} 
          </td>
          <td>
            {{ $result->data2 }}
          </td>
          <td colspan="2">
            {{ $result->data3 }}
          </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```